# Spaces not lining up right in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, textarea

I'm having a weird problem with the output of a JTextArea in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuDzs.png) . What my program is meant to do is accept an input string through the GUI, save it as an image, and set each pixel that's value is > 0 to '*'. This works completely find in the console, but when it's printed to the JTextArea, the spaces seem to be half the size of the '*'. I know this problem isn't an actual problem with my code, but just rather some built in thing with JTextAreas. I will include the code below, but the only line I feel is relevant is right at the end: tA.setText(output);

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.GlyphVector;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.Raster;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Project4 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

public static Project4 p = new Project4();
public static JTextField input = new JTextField("Java 2D");
public static JTextArea tA = new JTextArea();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Project 4");
    frame.setSize(600, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    input.setColumns(40);
    panel.add(input);       
    JButton print = new JButton("Print");
    print.addActionListener(p);
    panel.add(print);
    panel.add(tA);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Font f = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 20);
    FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(null, false, false);
    GlyphVector gv = f.createGlyphVector(frc, input.getText());
    Rectangle2D bounds = gv.getLogicalBounds();
    TextLayout tL = new TextLayout(input.getText(), f, frc);
    float ascent = tL.getAscent();
    BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage((int) bounds.getWidth(), 
        (int) bounds.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
    Graphics2D g2 = b.createGraphics();
    g2.drawGlyphVector(gv, 0, ascent);
    g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
    g2.drawString(input.getText(), input.getAlignmentX(), input.getAlignmentY());

    String output = "", line = "";
    int spaceCount = 0;
    Raster r = b.getRaster();
    int[] i = new int[1];
    for (int y = 0; y < (int) bounds.getHeight() - 1; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < (int) bounds.getWidth() - 1; x++) {
            r.getPixel(x, y, i);
            int pixel = i[0];
            if (pixel > 0) {
                line += "*";
            } else {
                line += " ";
                spaceCount++;
            }
        }

        if (spaceCount != line.length())
            output += line + "\n";
        spaceCount = 0;
        line = "";
    }

    System.out.print(output);
    tA.setText(output);
}

}
```

** Thanks for the edit, Fast Snail!

Comment: Try using a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), like Courier.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the font unless I can change the font of the JTextArea. If you see, it's fine in the console but bad in the GUI. I suppose they could be different fonts, but is this something I can set in the JTextArea alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font being used by the `JTextArea` is using a variable width font. In order to make sure your spaces and characters take up equal amounts of space, you'll want to use a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), like Courier New. You can set that on the `JTextArea` as well as use it for rastering the glyphs. This should be all you need in your `actionPerformed`.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Font f = new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 20);
    tA.setFont(f);
```

Alternatively, you could create a `static` variable for the font and only assign it once to your `JTextArea` and re-use it in your `actionPerformed`.

The reason it works in your console is because that is using a monospaced font, which is pretty common for console outputs.

I should note, the font you use to raster the glyphs doesn't have to match the one you use for your output in the `JTextArea`. You can use a non-monospaced font for rendering your glyphs, but your ASCII-like output in the `JTextArea` should use a monospaced font.

Comment: Such a simple fix... should've just looked at the documentation for the JTextArea haha well thanks a lot! Silly, late night mistakes!